# Change the default Devise GET user path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to change the default path of some user (in this case with id = 1) information from:

```
domain.com/user.1
```

to

```
domain.com/user/1
```

I already use `devise_for` on my route.rb, is there some special command to do what I need with this?

---

this is my `route.rb`

```
devise_for :users,
    :path => '',
    :path_names => {
        :sign_in => 'login',
        :sign_out => 'logout',
        :sign_up => 'register'
    },
    :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `domain.com/user.1` doesn't look like a real route to me. Are you sure you're not calling `users_path(id)` when you intend to call `user_path(id)`?

Also, a `user/:id` route doesn't look like it has anything to do with Devise, which is concerned with authentication/authorization. It looks more like a show resource method that would go in `UsersController#show`.

In any case, the following route should give you the `/user/:id` route which maps to `UsersController#show`

```
resources :user
```

which would create the following route helper method:

```
user_path(id)
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm lil bit confused on Devise-UserController works. You've cleared the ideas! Thanks!